# System backup into a git repository?

Tags: git, backup

It has just occurred to me that git (or a git wrapper of some sort) might be a good tool for system backups or hard drive backups. Why am I thinking that, I am not sure, as I am a git newbie and have no idea how efficient, reliable or straightforward it is with huge repositories, how well it compresses or whether it is friendly towards external compression, etc; just thinking it might be neat. Is it feasible? Desirable? Has anyone implemented it? Is there a straightforward way to implement it, preferably using open source software? (system backups can be tricky).

Comment: Git is simply a folder. Your forget to explain why git is better than old good zip archive.

Comment: Does old good zip archive offer version control?

Comment: The point of backup is making a copy. When you want to backup all previous version, you backup (zip) the git folder and transfer it over into another storage device.

Comment: Technically correct, but I don't see how it answers my question. Sure, once I've managed to backup my system into git, I can easily make copies of the entire backup, with versions and all, using zip (though at that point, that would probably be impractical, given how much disk space that would require). So, what are pros and cons of backing up my system into git? Can it be compressed easily, etc? A newbie question, I know.

Comment: I have told you that you do not backup into git. You use the git and back it up time after time.

Comment: And I have told you that I am seeking to use git for incremental system backup. I had not asked how to back up a git folder, that's obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bup`](https://github.com/bup/bup):

> Highly efficient file backup system based on the git packfile format. Capable of doing *fast* incremental backups of virtual machine images.

AFAIK, an important `bup`'s limitation currently is its inability to purge old data.

I should add that from my personal experience [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) (in the "preserve hard links" mode) + [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) work just OK for backing up mostly unchanging data. [`dirvish`](http://www.dirvish.org/) is reported to also be OK, and so does [`unison`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (though I'd say it's mostly a synchronisation tool rather than a backup solution).

You might also take a look at [`obnam`](http://liw.fi/obnam/) and [`BackupPC`](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) — they use different approaches but perform data deduplication largely providing for the same outcome you'd get with Git and its "reusing" of blobs which are already in the repository.

Note that certain "next gen" filesystems, such as `zfs` and `btrfs` might do file-level (and/or block-level?) deduplication by themsevles, and hence backing up mostly unchanging data might be done by just copying it over and over to a set of per-backup-event directories on a single instance of such filesystem.

Comment: Thank you @kostix. As a Stackoverflow newbie, I am wondering, why was my question downvoted? Is it inappropriate in some way?

Comment: @user2712050, it's hard to tell exactly. One reason might be that such a question is better asked on some other stackexchange site such as "sysadmins" or "unix" because it appears to be more about backups and not about using Git. I did not perceive your question as strictly not meeting SO criteria, but different people have different opinions, you know ;-)